# How can I find rows and columns for a specific given value in the matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, rows

I have a data with points and games for 10 players in the NBA.

I wanted to find out who has the highest points per game in basketball from 2005 to 2014 and wrote the following code:

To find PPG for every player, I worte this:

```
Points
P<-round(Points/Games,2)
P
```

To find the highest PPG,

```
M<-max(P,na.rm=T)
```

and got the output of 35.4

Now, I know it is kobe bryant just by looking at the matrix. But how can write a code to get the row and column for that element?

*Data source: Superdatascience*

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Next time try to include sample data. It helps us help you.  Her is a solution using the `dplyr` package.  It is part of the `tidyverse` dialect of `R`.  If you are just learning `R`, install the Tidyverse suite of packages.  It will be your best friend.

```
data <- data.frame(points = c(10, 12, 12, 4), 
                   games = c(2, 3, 2, 1), 
                   dude = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

library(dplyr) 
theDude <- data %>%  #start with the data above and pipe it to the next line
    mutate(pointsPerGame = points/games) %>%   # create the average variable and pipe to next line
    filter(pointsPerGame == max(pointsPerGame)) %>%  # keep only the record(s) with the largest average and pipe to the next line
    select(dude) # keep the person's name
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `which` with option `arr.ind = TRUE`

```
which(P == max(P),arr.ind = TRUE)
```